# Apple Push Notifications in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, tvos

Hi i am a newbie to tvOS. I have an TV application which is registered for APNS.

But while i push a notification i am not able to get the notifications.
i am getting  the device token but not the notification.

While i try with the Mobile Devices i am getting the notifications,But not in the tvOS why is it so...?

How can i solve this..?

```
   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in


        if granted == true
        {
            print("Allow")
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Don't Allow")
        }
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
     print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceTokenString)")
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Currently push notifications are not generally supported on tvOS. You can get CloudKit sync notifications but that is all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191951/tvos-remote-notification-replacement?rq=1

Comment: but i  am able to register and retrieve device token

Comment: Yes, this is in order to receive CloudKit notifications, but other notifications will not be received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tvOS supports only 2 types of notifications: `badges` and `content-available`. So you need to send one of these two types to APNS. Any of these types notification only changes badge number on App Icon. And only the lastest notification will be delivered to your application when you open the app. There is no visual presentation of notification as it was on iOS
How it looks see on presentation from [WWDC 2016/Session 206/tvOS, start watching from 21:20](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/206a38wgme6uponcuwd/206/206_hd_whats_new_in_tvos.mp4?out=%5B2016%5D)

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
On tvOS 11 appeared `Silent notifications` which wakes the application up and allow to refresh content in background

[image]

[WWDC 2017 watch from 7:50](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/209dzcjsnhy5ju/209/209_hd_whats_new_in_tvos.mp4?out=%5B2017%5D)

Comment: Does that mean you can't sent any payload to TV?

Comment: No, it doesn’t mean that. You can send payload like for iOS.

Comment: What does it mean Delivers every notification ? I have not seen anything regarding this in that video.

Comment: @UdayKumarEega I already don't remember exactly, bu probably that means every notification reached your device will be pass through to the app

Comment: Thank you for this info, but can you link the exact videos please (and not the list of WWDC videos)? The first video in your post is titled 'What's new in Apple's PushNotification Service' in the WWDC16 video list and it has only 14 mins, contrasted with your suggestion to continue watching it from 21 mins. I don't know if I'm looking at the right video or not. Similar problems with the second video suggestion.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD thank you for pointing the issue. I fixed the links

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for Notifications in tvOS.

in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // set self (AppDelegate) to handle notification
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    // Request permission from user to send notification

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { authorized, error in
      if authorized {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
      }
    })


    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    //print(userInfo)
    print("Notification Received")
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.post(name: Notification.Name("foo"), object: nil) 

}
```

The first function provide the permission necessary for notification.

And the second function received the notification and send a notification to the current viewcontroller and make the magic happpend.

This is the viewcontroller

```
//viewload  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateTable(_ :)), name: Notification.Name("foo"), object: nil)
```