# PubNub Push Notification For Apple TV Application

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, tvos, pubnub

Is it possible to send push notification using pubnub in apple tv application , like we use to do in mobile application. Went through pubnub docs as well but didn't find anything specific for Apple TV implementation.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139057/apple-push-notifications-in-tvos

Comment: thanks dennis, but my requirement is not to use APNS but to use pubnub only and user should receive notification only when app is in foreground. Pretty straight forward requirement but cannot find any docs on pubnub for simple apple tv pubnub integration.

Comment: OK, but you did say "push notification" which is commonly used to refer to mobile push notifications (APNS or GCM). But the term "push" is a bit overused. We'll find you some how-to on this.

Comment: There is this PubNub blog, [Building a tvOS Smart Home Controller](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-07-13-building-a-tvos-smart-home-controller/), that should give you what you need. Review that, give it a go and you can send more questions to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) where we can get into the details and post back answer here.

Answer (score 3):

## PubNub - Sending Mobile Push Notifications

You can send a mobile push message any platform. This only requires that you include the proper mobile push payload in the message that you publish.  This includes **Apple TV Apps**.

> **Yes.** It is possible to send push notification using PubNub in apple tv application.

[image: Combine APNS and FCM/GCM Push Notifications]

#### Combine APNS and FCM/GCM Push Notifications

Dictionary objects sent to APNS and GCM mobile services must be in a well-formed format in order for the remote service (operated by Apple, Google, etc) to process.

For example, when sending native APNS and GCM alerts to Apple and Google via PubNub, you could send in this format:

```js
{
    "name" : "Fitchwitz Technology",
    "pn_gcm": {
        "data": {
            "title_for_mobile": "Fitchwitz Technology",
            "summary_for_mobile": [ "Fitchwitz antivirals... more info at http://FitchwitzTech.com/fooz" ]
        }
    },
    "pn_apns" : {
        "aps" : {
            "alert" : "Fitchwitz Technology",
            "badge": 2,
            "summary_for_mobile": "Fitchwitz antivirals... more info at http://FitchwitzTech.com/fooz"
        }
    }
}
```

Please review the article, [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006344), for full details.

Comment: To be clear, I answered the question "How to send push notifications **from** AppleTV and not **to** AppleTV. The comment above from Dennis Weidmann addresses sending **to** AppleTV. So you can use the message content and publish that to PubNub channel if your AppleTV is configured to receive push notifications with PubNub.

Comment: i want to send push notification from pubnub dashboard to apple tv application. Is there any documentation for the same.